# How much more efficient is 240 V than 120 V?

Tags: voltage, efficiency

I've got a PHEV that currently uses a level 1 (120 V) charger, which works fine and can do a full charge overnight. It's fairly trivial to upgrade to a 240 V circuit, but I'd have to buy a level 2 EVSE.

How much would I really save in terms of actual power usage with a 240 V circuit over a 120 V, if I'm pushing the same amount of power through it in the end? Is the decreased resistance trivial in terms of consumed power, or would I notice a difference?

Comment: Welcome! What does the datasheet say?

Comment: From 240V you can get more current and faster charge. It is all about the charger cost.

Comment: You probably want to spell out what PHEV and EVSE are.

Comment: The dominant factor for _power efficiency_ here is (with some possible but somewhat unlikely exceptions) probably not the ohmic losses from the increased current in the mains wiring, but rather the efficiency of the AC-DC converter at different AC input voltages. You'd have to check the datasheet for the charger to find out exactly what the efficiency ratings are for 120V and 240V. It's also worth noting that the charging _rate_ and charging _efficiency_ are separate matters.

Comment: @jcaron it is about electrical vehicles.

Comment: @jcaron Plug-in Hybrid Electric Vehicle, and Electric Vehicle Supply Equipment.

Comment: You may or may not get an efficiency gain.  What you will get for sure is a SPEED gain.   Power = Volts * Amps.   If you double the available volts, you double the watts going into the system.

Comment: But that's not all.   Most 120V circuits have 15 or 20A breakers (per code)  But a 240V can be much higher... 30 or 40A per breaker.  So you not only get the voltage increase, you get a potential CURRENT increase as well.   Reasonable, all else being equal, you could have DOUBLE the voltage and DOUBLE the current, yeilding FOUR TIMES as much power.  i.e. you could charge the battery in 1/4 the time.     Keeping in mind also, this may shorten battery life.  The slower you charge them, the longer they last.....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are (at least) a couple of places where charging from 240V provides higher efficiency. Some reasons are because of the higher voltage others because of the higher power available from a 240V source. 120V sources are usually limited to about 1.4kW (120V @ 12A) where 240V sources can commonly supply up to 7.2kW or even 11kW.

1: The charger itself that is internal to the vehicle is usually of higher efficiency at 240V as various losses such as diode and cable voltage drops are a lower proportion of the input voltage.

2: The various active control modules, fans, circulation pumps etc in the vehicle take the same power whether charging at 120V or 240V. Since the total charging time will be less when charging from 240V the amount of energy consumed by these parasitic loads will be less when charging at the higher power levels that 240V allows. This parasitic power that doesn't contribute to charging the battery can be of the order of 100-200W so can make a big difference when charging from 120V which limits the total input power to about 1400W.

3: Heaters required to bring the battery up to the temperature required to charge. Lithium-Ion batteries cannot in general be charged below about 0°C or a phenomenon known as "lithium plating" occurs which permanently loses active material. With a 120V supply it may be that the heater power available can never bring the battery up to temperature in which case the efficiency is 0%. At high ambient temperatures it is possible that cooling is required though this would be extremely unusual.

I measured the efficiency of both 120V and 240V for my Spark EV (not a PHEV but the same logic applies) and determined that the charger efficiency from 120V was about 78% while about 92% when 240V was used.

The monitoring for my Tesla Model 3 gives very similar figures of about 81% for 120V and 93% for 240V.

These efficiencies are at moderate temperatures so heating (or cooling) were not required.

Comment: That’s an unexpectedly big difference but there’s no arguing with the facts.

Comment: @Frog  The parasitic power is a very significant amount when limited to 1.4kW charging from 120V.

Comment: `at 240V as various losses such as diode and cable voltage drops are a higher proportion of the input voltage`  I think you mean that the other way around, i.e. at 240V they are a *lower* proportion of the input voltage?

Comment: I read the same issue with the proportion statement. I considered editing the answer but seeing the detailed comment from @Michael decided to leave that to Kevin White to fix on their own.

Comment: @Kevin White what's parasitic power in this context?

Comment: @Frog - the the power required for various functions that don't don't contribute directly to charging - fans, circulating pumps, control circuitry.

Comment: @Michael - thanks. That's what I meant.